# ! Paragraph ended before \doTocEntry was complete

Tags: table-of-contents, paragraphs, tex4ht, compilation-error, latex2html

I'm writing my thesis and stuck here.
Below is my preamble and some code.
I'm knew to latex and Don't know what is the problem with the code.

```
\documentclass[twosided,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[authoryear,sort]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={,}} 
\usepackage{har2nat}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{setspace}
\chapternumberfont{\LARGE}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    paper=a4paper,
    inner=23mm,         % Inner margin
    outer=22mm,         % Outer margin
    bindingoffset=10mm, % Binding offset
    top=30mm,           % Top margin
    bottom=30mm        % Bottom margin         
}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,rotating,booktabs}
\usepackage{realboxes}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
%
\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \doublespacing
\begin{doublespace}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
\end{doublespace}
%
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth,height=0.30\textheight]{xxx}%
\caption[ABC]{abc}
\label{fig:lbl}
\end{figure}%
   \subparagraph{SWS}
    The Diatoms in the ......Table.\ref{tab:xxx}. .....\par
    %
    \begin{table}[!htb]%
        \centering
        \caption[ABC.]{xyz \% IRI for each season. PrM (pre-monsoon), M (monsoon) and pm (post-monsoon); SD - Standard Deviation and CV - Coefficient of Variation.}
        \label{tab:zzz}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{@{}cccccccccc@{}}
            \toprule
            Species             & PrM    & SD    & CV    & M      & SD    & CV    & pm     & SD    & CV    \\ \midrule
            Diatoms             & 86.119 & 6.141 & 0.071 & 90.482 & 6.684 & 0.074 & 92.551 & 2.124 & 0.023 \\
            Dinoflagellates     & 6.156  & 4.201 & 0.683 & 2.982  & 2.222 & 0.745 & 3.284  & 1.606 & 0.489 \\
            Copepods            & 1.630  & 0.480 & 0.294 & 0.736  & 0.747 & 1.015 & 1.589  & 1.085 & 0.683 \\
            Tintinnids          & 3.903  & 1.584 & 0.406 & 1.639  & 0.597 & 0.364 & 1.204  & 0.989 & 0.822 \\
            Zooplankton         & 0.000  & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000  & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000  & 0.000 & 0.000 \\
            Cladoceran          & 0.000  & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.001  & 0.002 & 1.283 & 0.000  & 0.000 & 0.000 \\
            Detritus            & 0.000  & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000  & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000  & 0.000 & 0.000 \\
            Fish egg            & 0.176  & 0.146 & 0.832 & 0.101  & 0.169 & 1.665 & 0.029  & 0.023 & 0.766 \\
            Foraminifera        & 0.000  & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000  & 0.000 & 1.170 & 0.002  & 0.001 & 0.500 \\
            Copepod egg         & 0.249  & 0.291 & 1.164 & 0.177  & 0.354 & 2.000 & 0.000  & 0.000 & 0.500 \\
            Dinoflagellate cyst & 0.000  & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000  & 0.000 & 1.170 & 0.002  & 0.001 & 0.500 \\
            Others              & 1.767  & 0.389 & 0.220 & 3.881  & 4.625 & 1.192 & 1.336  & 0.432 & 0.323 \\
            Sand                & 0.000  & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000  & 0.000 & 0.004 & 0.004  & 0.003 & 0.907 \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
        }
    \end{table}%
This is next paragraph
%
\end{document}
```

`pdflatex` is running ok and output is obtained
but `hlatex` showing error while trying to obtain an Html output

```
    Runaway argument?
{\csname a:TocLink\endcsname {1}{x1-18002}{}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces \ETC
.
! Paragraph ended before \doTocEntry was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.34 \par
         
?
```

Comment: Latex code successfully gives a pdf output, however, while trying for an html output with text4ht it produces the error "! Paragraph ended before \doTocEntry was complete.". Not able to understand the issue.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be helpful if you provided a little more context for others to understand what you're trying to do, and what is not working. Also, while your example _is_ helpful, it is probably not enough. It is always more helpful if you provide a complete example that others can just copy-paste and compile themselves, so it should begin with `\documentclass{...}` and end with `\end{document}`. You can look [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/201628) for tips on examples to include in questions on this site.

Comment: I don't get any compilation error for your file, there are only some formatting issues, caused by package clashes. Do you use up-to date TeX distribution?

Comment: I figured out that text4ht shows the error while compiling some figures and tables in it (only some). I checked for any extra '{' and '(' in the caption but everything is ok. Yet the error exists. How can I know what is actually causing the problem?

Comment: @Sajnav.h do you get this error for this example? you may just have an older installation, where some bugs aren't fixed yet.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get any compilation error for your MWE, but there are some issues:
[image]

You can see that there are two colons in the figure caption, and the `\subparagraph` command produces several separate lines. These issues are caused by the `caption` and `titlesec` packages. The fixes are already incorporated in the TeX4ht sources, so they should be avalable in TeX Live in few days. In the meantime, you can use the following configuration file that contains the fixes, `myconfig.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\catcode`\:=11
\makeatletter

% fix for titlesec
\def\:tempc#1#2#3#4{%
  \begingroup
  \let\everypar\@gobble% we must prevent titlesec from touching of \everypar
  \edef\sc:tp{\ifttl@label\else like\fi #1}%
   \let\ttl@savewrite\empty
   \o:ttl@select:{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
   \endgroup
}
\HLet\ttl@select\:tempc

% fix for caption

\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \caption@make@above%
  \cptA:\caption@@make{\cap:ref{#1}}{\cptC:#2}\cptD:%
  \caption@make@below%
}
\makeatother
\catcode`\:=12
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Compile your file using

```
make4ht -c myconfig.cfg filename.tex
```

This is the result:

[image]

BTW, please don't use `htlatex`, it is deprecated. `make4ht` is the recommended tool to convert your TeX file with TeX4ht.